# Could'nt get data from database with limit in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get data from database with limit like this but dont work:

```
topic.find({}).limit(10).exec(function(err,topic){topic2.find({}).limit(5).exec(function(err,topic2){console.log(topic+topic2)}}))
```

But if i try with this(only change the limit of outside and inside) ,it works.So i want to learn why:

```
topic.find({}).limit(5).exec(function(err,topic){topic2.find({}).limit(10).exec(function(err,topic2){console.log(topic+topic2)}}))
```

Comment: **If inside limit value >= outside limit value ,it works.**But why?